# EditText + String in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, nfc

I'm working on an app to write NFC tags. The layout has an `EditText` to enter the URL to write and a `Button` to save in NFC tag.
My question is the following:
How can I add a fixed `String` to the text entered in the `EditText`? For example:

Instead of
Text entered: `45`
Text written: `45`

Should be:
Text entered: `45`
Text written: `http://myweb.com?id=45`
URL (The user never sees this, but is set internally in the app and will be saved in the NFC tag): http://myweb.com?id=

I'm from php side, but I don't know how to do this in android. In php it should be like this:

```
$Formula = '$URL'.'$TextEntered';
```

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      your_formular="http://myweb.com?id=" + s.toString();
   }
  });
```

Comment: I'm a little bit noob in android.. and i dont programm the actual app, but i know this is a simple thing to change so i preffer to do it myself.

Comment: So, where i should add that code? in the Android manifest, or in the ActivityMain.xml or where exactly?

Comment: In java code, right after you get the instance of edittext